# Matrix of vectors in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

Is it possible to create matrix of vectors in R? I mean the elements of this matrix must be vectors. For example `mat[1,3] == c(6,8,9)`

i must create 40x40 matrix and i need to fill it manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a `matrix` but an `array`:

```
myarray <- array(1:24, c(2,4,3))
myarray[1,3,]
#[1]  5 13 21
```

Comment: i can't use this. i need 40x40 matrix and i need to fill the matrix manually.

Comment: Of course you can use this. An array is just a higher dimensional extension of the matrix concept and works more or less in the same way.

Comment: if this doesn't work for you, it would probably be a good idea to provide a bit more context and explain *why* you can't use this.  To fill the array manually as above you would just say `myarray <- array(dim=c(40,40,3)); mat[1,3,] <- c(6,8,9)` and so forth ...

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can add dimensions to a list, so that it resembles a matrix where the elements can be anything you want, including vectors of different length. For example:

```
foo <- as.list(numeric(2^2))
dim(foo) <- c(2,2)

# Assignment per element:
foo[[1,1]] <- 1:4
foo[[1,2]] <- 1:10
foo[[2,1]] <- "foo"
foo[[2,2]] <- list(foo)
```

Gives you a weird looking object:

```
> foo
     [,1]      [,2]      
[1,] Integer,4 Integer,10
[2,] "foo"     List,1
```

Where each element basically is a vector. Still, this is hardly ever the best way of doing this. If the vectors are the same length an array as described by Roland is much more appropriate.

Comment: If I am right the first line has a bug that can be misleading.. it should be foo <- as.list(numeric(2*2)) for the case of 2 the result is the same but for any other it is different...