# How could a matrix hold different data types when coercing from a list?

Tags: r, matrix

[As commonly known](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html), a matrix can only hold one data type.

But it seems like I can coerce a list into a matrix just fine.

```
tmp <- matrix(list(1, "a"))
class(tmp)
```

> [1] "matrix"

```
str(tmp)
```

> List of 2
>
> $ : num 1
>
> $ : chr "a"
>
> - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 1

Is this behavior documented?

Comment: It seems to be hinted at in various parts of `?matrix`: *"The print method for a matrix gives a rectangular layout with dimnames or indices. **For a list matrix**, the entries of length not one are printed in the form integer,7 indicating the type and length."* E.g., `matrix(list(1:5, "a"))`

Comment: Technically, it might be clearer to say that a matrix (array) is simply a vector that also has a dimension attribute. The normal notion of a matrix containing only a single (atomic) type applies in the case of an atomic vector with a dim attribute. But a list is a vector too (no matter what `is.vector` says, use `is(...,"vector")` instead).

Comment: @joran Thinking about matrix as a vector with dimension does help make sense of this situation. Then does it mean the statement about "matrix can only hold one data type" wrong?

Comment: I don't think so, because a list *is* a data type. `typeof(matrix(list(1, "a")))`.  The confusing part is that it's a data type that can hold any number of other data types.

Comment: Eh, technically not, as Rich suggests, but I agree it's a bit of useful simplification perhaps, if confusing. Creating a list with a dimension attribute is a bit of a corner case (**ahem** `sapply` **ahem**) and typically the most common confusion people encounter is the notion that data frames are intended to be used for data of different types, whereas matrices are _intended_ generally to be used for single atomic types.

Comment: It makes sense now, if any of you want to turn this into an answer, I'd be happy to check mark.

Comment: Some relevant comments and excercises here: [How to create a matrix of lists in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007890/how-to-create-a-matrix-of-lists-in-r).

Comment: And because you were linking to [Hadley's Data structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) in your question: it's obvious that you stopped reading before the quiz (Q5). ;)

Answer (score 2):

(This is my first time answering so formatting tips and suggestions are welcome)
This is because its not a matrix of vectors, its a matrix of lists! To be more clear, the one 'type' matrix is holding is the data structure type called lists.  And List *are not one dimensional in R but n-dimensional!*  In R, this means that lists ability to handle different data types with ease allows other functions like matrix to break there own limits and handle multi-data types.  In fact to paraphrase my professor, it is the precisely this n-dimensional power of R's version of lists is one of the top 10 reasons R handles Big Data better than java or python languages

As @nrussel pointed out thought the `matrix()` documenation only hints at this behavior and there is no exact documentation of matrix-list combinations; however, I will show a simple code will help clarify this behavior then show how supported by various websites.  My sample code inspired from another question answered by `42-[1]` in stack overflow:

```
    tmp <- matrix(list(1, "a"))
    str(tmp)
```

> ```
> > List of 2
> >
> > $ : num 1
> > 
> > $ : chr "a"
> >
> > attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 1
> ```

```
    class(tmp)
```

> "matrix"

```
    is.matrix(tmp)
    is.list(tmp)
    is.array(tmp)
```

> TRUE TRUE TRUE

```
    tmp <- matrix(list(c(1,2), c("a","b"))
    str(tmp)
```

> List of 2
>
> $ : num [1:2] 1 2
>
> $ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
>
> attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 1

So what is going on here?   Although beginner R tutorials[2] sometimes oversimplify list`[3]`, lists in R are *not* like vectors and are *not exactly 1 dimensional (1D)*.  Unlike other languages, *list are really `1 x (n x m)` dimensional (1nD)*. (Aside: list are even sometimes be `1 x (n x m ... n+1)`, but I will explain this later).  Like most languages, a list is collection of data structures.

So again what is going on here in the above example?   Look at the output above for first `str(tmp)`, `is.matrix`, and `is.list`.  `class()` and `is.matrix`, tell us the overall function is a matrix.  `str()` tells use however, that inside the maxtrix is a list.  `Str()` tells use that each list its only a list of 1 value meaning its only a 1 x 1 list.  So its 1 x 2 matrix of 1 x 1 lists.  This is why `is.list()` gives the value TRUE because technically there are only lists in the matrix.

Now let's talk more about list as we look at the second example in the code or second `str(tmp)`.  Like most languages, a list is collection of data structures. The parts of a list can be simply vectors, like a data.frame, but with the columns are allowed to have a different lengths and data types. However unlike other languages, a list in R can also be a much more complicated structure (paraphrased from ramnathv`[3]`).  Looking above, see that `[1:2]`? The `[number:number]` line tells use that each internal list in our second example is 1 x 2.  However, `str(tmp)` is still telling us that our matrix is still only 1 x 2.  This is because the matrix only lists as individuals, and matrix is behaving like 1 x 2 vector. Combining the list and matrix observations, overall the matrix lists has dimension of `1 x (2 x (1 x 2))`. Its two `1 x 2's`.  This `1 x (2 x (1 x 2)` format is shows what I meant by lists being `1 x (n x m)` dimensional and what ramnathv meant by lists 'complicated structure'.  Since behavior of combining lists with arrays might still not be clear lets delve a bit deeper than one normally might into this "complicated structure" of lists.

==== Deeper meaning of Lists being nD allow matrix of lists to have ====

Paul Murrell`[6]` when talking about lists complicated structure noted how:

> In R lists act as containers. Unlike (regular) atomic vectors, the contents of a list are not restricted to a single mode and can encompass any mixture of data types. Lists are sometimes called recursive vectors, because a list can contain other lists. This makes them fundamentally different from (regular) atomic vectors.

By atomic vector, Paul is talking about what most other people call vectors. (In R regular numerical or character vectors are not called vectors but atomic vectors in order to distinguish them from generalized vectors like lists.) To illustrate what Paul Murrell means in the above quote lets look at another more complicated list. And then look at recursive vector lists when combined with matrices.

```
    tmp1 <- matrix(list(c(1,2,3),c("a","b","c","d"),as.factor("soup")))
    str(tmp1)
```

> List of 2
>
> $ : num [1:3] 1 2 3
>
> $ : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
>
> $ : Factor w/ 1 level "soup": 1
>
> attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 1

Recursive Matrix Lists

```
    tmp2 <- matrix(list(c(1,2,3),c("a","b","c"),list(c(1,2,3),c("a","b","c"))))
    str(tmp2)
    tmp3 <- matrix(list(c(1,2,3),c("a","b","c"),matrix(list(c(1,2,3),c("a","b","c")))))
    str(tmp3)
```

> I will leave the output for you to discover.

In the first example, we see I hope just different Lists in R can be from atomic vectors.  In this list we see not only that lists can have different 1 x n sizes, and not only completely different types, but list can hold data structures (ex. factor).  Factor believe it or not is not a data type but the most generalized form of vector that R has`[4]`; a vector that cares not for its data is homogenious in type`[5]`).  I am going to have to wave my hands with the math of what str(tmp1) tell us, but overall  matrix list is now `(1 x 3*) or 1 x ((1 x 3) + (1 x 4) + (1 x 1))`. Yet the matrix itself thinks its only a  In this list of list example, list is allow the matrix to act like a true generalized table of structured data that is not the same by variable type, number of rows, or variable class. It is miles simpler then trying to create the same generalized structure in java or python.  I hope you can see how it bring the conversation full circle to my point at the beginning....

> **The TLDR Answer:** List in R are n dimensional not 1 dimensional!  In R, lists ability to handle different data types with ease allows other functions like *matrix* to break there own limitations and handle multi-data types.

However, list can also contain a list of themselves as shown by the last two pieces of code.  Literally I have posted two different ways a list could be used to pass in the same variables into itself as a new section of the list.  If I were to draw what the data table would look like, this recurision of list is like Infinity Mirror because it has a constantly folding dimension `(n + 1)` or is `1 x (n x m ... n+1)`.  I only bring this up to extend my answer to show how list-matrix has been used in R to allow a regular 2 x 2 matrix to represent an infinity matrix with only finite numbers (at least according to my professor that what he uses it for)

I hope this helped you understand lists better.  Sites like http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html have a typo when they call a list simply just a vector.  I hope this cleared up the confusion you had about lists being 1D data structures.

P.S. I could also use help with the formatting of stackoverflow.  Its a bit overwhelming.

```
    [1]: stackoverflow.com/questions/30007890/how-to-create-a-matrix-of-lists-in-r
    [2]: en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Data_types#Lists
    [3]: adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html
    [4]: www.r-bloggers.com/data-types-part-3-factors/
    [5]: www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_data_types.htm
    [6]: www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node64.html#SECTION001345000000000000000
    [7]: https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/learn/structures.html
```